# Can UIView's children be constrained to their parent's frame

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, ios4

I have a custom `UIView` that acts as a layout object. If I add children to that `UIView` (layout), the layout takes care of their positioning (using the `layoutSubviews` method). Is it possible to constrain the children in such a way, so that they are not drawn outside the layout's bounds?

Below is an illustration of what I want to achieve:

[image: Normal behavior] [image: desired behavior]

The left picture is what would normally happen. I want to achieve the situation in the right picture.

**Please note, I do not want to redraw over the Button**, I just want it not to be drawn outside its parent.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your parent view `clipsToBounds` property to `YES`